# .htaccess URL rewriting not working on pagination?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this following url `localhost/test/index.php?page=1` And i want it to be 
'index.php/page/1'
so far I have this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^page/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

But it's not working .Any suggestion what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You don't have `page/numbers` in your URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ index.php/?page=$1 [L]
```

If you set it correct then URL like this `http://localhost/test/page/1` should work

Comment: Nothing's changed .remain same

Comment: with this code you should get it right when you go to http://localhost/page/1
have you tried it? you can remove `/test` to have it as root folder. then you access it with http://localhost/test/page/1

Comment: if i remove the test which is my testing server i will no longer be able to access the index.php file

Comment: I mean `/test` from my code. Look updated answer. I tested this and it works so you must do something wrong

Comment: if i test it like putting the `index.php/page/1` i get the result but however if i first load the index.php and then click on of my pagination link it still displays 'index.php?page=1';

Comment: thats because you didn't set links to lead to new url's.. it doesn't automatically change your existing links.. you have to set them

Comment: How am i suppose to do that with pagination.I am not sure how many links i am going to have.I am kinda noob to this .htaccess things.

Comment: it has nothing to do with htaccess.. you set it and thats it. you need to find php code where you generate pagination links and change it there from for example `index.php?page=$someid` to `page/$someid`

Comment: So you do something wrong. But that is the issue for another question probably. We solved your htaccess problem here

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/page/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$2 [NC,L]
```

The url will be

```
localhost/test/index.php/page/123
```

If you want the url looks like

```
localhost/test/index.php/page/123/
```

change you rule into this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/page/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: tired it but url remains same

Comment: You want  to remove your localhost/test from your HTTP_HOST line and open your index.php just from address bar?

Comment: Nah.it should actually look like this `localhost/test/index.php/page/1 or 2`

Comment: Perhaps you should add 

RewriteBase   /test 

before the rule

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteRule ^index.php\/page\/(.*?)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

The above code should solve your probleem. But you may want to read up on mod_url_rewrite

See https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting for more info

Comment: `/`s don't need to be escaped, there is no delimiter on mod-rewrites.